# How to create clean url for profile users in htaccess while i already using for article which is working fine

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

It is a very common question on the internet but unfortunately, I didn't find any solution yet. My issue is, I already using below codes, which is working fine for article purpose (site.com/my-first-article).

```
#remove .php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#for pretty url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ blog.php?qTitle=$1 [NC,L]
```

But now i need (site.com/profile/user-name), when I copy and edit the code above for user profile it doesn't work.

```
#remove .php    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

#for pretty url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

I hope I defined the question well and some can understand my issue. Thanks for your time.

My output

[image]

Comment: Why did you remove blog redirection?

Comment: You could route all the incoming requests through index.php and then decide within PHP what you gonna do with the request instead (redirect using: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: F. Muller, how to route all incoming requests?

Comment: vivek how i removed blog redirection that is working fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "it does not work"? What have you tried to check what is going wrong?

Comment: I removed RewriteEngine On
# If user directly accesses /profile/[username]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L] from htaccess file, the result is the same

Comment: I mean the site.com/profile/username  page is still the same as it was in the existance of htaccess redirect rule

Answer (score 0):

To change the address `site.com/profile.php?username=J0R1AN` to `site.com/profile/J0R1AN` for example, you would need to use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If user directly accesses /profile/[username]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?profile/(.*?)/?$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
# If user accesses /profile.php?username=[username]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /profile\.php\?username=([^\&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^/?profile\.php$ /profile/%1? [L,R=301]
```

You can even keep using `$_GET` in the profile.php file

Source: https://www.taniarascia.com/rewrite-query-string-to-path-with-htaccess/

Comment: still not working I'm gonna to upload screenshot of what the result I'm getting.

Comment: The redirection is working fine, but it looks like the CSS is not loading properly. Could you tell me the path of your css file and the path in your <head>?

Comment: src="css/bootstrap.min.css" and more css files are the same

Comment: Could you try putting a / in from of the path? That way it goes from the root of the page no matter where you are. Also, could you give the directory if the css file itself, I expect it to just be a css folder in the root directory but just to be sure

Comment: even i added project ( src="blog/css/style.css" ) still not working

Comment: i think this is not css issue, because this happens when i didn't put the code you send for profile.php?username=john

Comment: I mean like `src="/css/style.css"` and the same with bootstrap. Do you have a directory `blog` in your root folder? If so, you should change it to `src="/blog/css/style.css"`

Comment: Just so I understand, the problem you are having right now is that the styling of the page looks off. Because in the screenshot it shows the expected rewritten URL, right?

Comment: yes it works but now images are not displaying the same thing i have to do with img path?

Comment: Yes, that way it will always point to the right file since right now you are having issues with that.

Comment: is there any one common method like base url or any other,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What I always do is this: Let's say I have this file structure: `public_html/css/style.css` and my home page (index.php) is in `public_html/index.php` then in every file, I use `src="/css/style.css"` because this also works from inside other folders.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your kind response.and support, I appreciate it.

Comment: bro sorry, but its the same when i remove htaccess codes you sended..

Comment: This is a different issue. Try to first make the css and images work, without the .htaccess change. Then use the code I sent and see if that changes it.